# Javascript set timeout on a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I have a function that reads data from Web Sql and sends it to web service to insert data into SQL Server. All would be nice and easy if not the fact that it takes about 40 seconds for the web service to process all the information.
I have set a timeout on sending data out to web service but it does not seems to be working....When I have more than one row in a table it sends out only the first row and skips the remaining ones, so it means that timeout does not work.
Any help appreciated.

```
        db2.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM offlineCabinDefects', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                var airline = results.rows.item(i).Airline;
                var tail = results.rows.item(i).Tail;
                var fn = results.rows.item(i).FlightNumber;
                var ad = results.rows.item(i).ActionDate;
                var ca = results.rows.item(i).CabinArea;
                var ci = results.rows.item(i).CabinItem;
                var uf = results.rows.item(i).UnserviceableFlag;
                var rn = results.rows.item(i).RowNumber;
                var sn = results.rows.item(i).SeatNumber;
                var dscr = results.rows.item(i).Description;
                var r = results.rows.item(i).Revision;
                var user = results.rows.item(i).UserName;
                var pass = results.rows.item(i).Password;

                data2 = "{'Airline':'" + airline +
                            "','Tail':'" + tail +
                            "','FlightNumber':'" + fn +
                            "','ActionDate':'" + ad +
                            "','CabinArea':'" + ca +
                            "','CabinItem':'" + ci +
                            "','UnserviceableFlag':'" + uf +
                            "','RowNumber':'" + rn +
                            "','SeatNumber':'" + sn +
                            "','Description':'" + dscr +
                            "','Revision':'" + r +
                            "','UserName':'" + user +
                            "','Password':'" + pass + "'}";


                 setTimeout(sendWS(data2), 50000);
            }
            dropTable2();
            document.getElementById("offlineresult").innerHTML = ('');
            document.getElementById("offlinetbl").innerHTML = ('');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Take time to ensure the code you posted is complete.

Comment: what does look incomplete to you?

Comment: Have you tried Googling this before asking the question?

Comment: @user3545840 Did you see how the ending curly brace } didn't have a matching starting { ?  Then you can go from there.

Comment: aww. That is from ending Else statement that this code is in

Comment: What i would really like is a timeout on the loop itself not on a function sendWS, but cant figure it out because its a part of executesql

Answer (score 0):

Your function within the timeout is being executed immediately! If you're passing params, wrap it in an anonymous function else it will be executed immediately!

```
setTimeout(function() {
    sendWS(data2)
}, 50000);
```

Comment: That **setTimeout** code is currently inside a loop.  There might be a better way to restructure the code.

Comment: it did not work, using this statement none of the rows where sent to sendWS